# Vba to IE Click JavaScript button no Id

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am trying to write a vba to fill out a form details from excel and click a submit button using . I am new to vba and have got everything figured out except how to click the submit button.

My code is

```
Dim a
Set a = doc.getElementsByClassName("button")(1)
a.Click

Do While ie.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
```

No error comes up but it doesn't seem to do anything. Normally when the submit button is clicked a message pops up on screen saying "details uploaded", the URL doesn't change.

Source code from site is

```
<a class="button" onclick="document.getElementById('CustomTableInbox').innerHTML='';JS_UpdateTrack();" href="javascript:;">Submit</a>
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Have you tried a simply ie.document.getElementsByTagName("form")(0).Submit ?   Or, ie.document.querySelector(".buttons-div a").Click ?

Comment: ie.document.getElementsByClassName("buttons-div")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).FireEvent "onclick"

Comment: Any of those work?

Comment: That first one you suggested worked perfectly, thanks so much!  Don't seem to be able to accept it as an answer though.. sorry

Comment: I have added as an answer you can click. You can’t do that in comments. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Ie.document.getElementsByTagName("form")(0).submit
```

This gets the form by index and tag and then uses the submit method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refer an example below may help you to solve your issue.

HTML code:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Sample Page</h2>
<a href="http:\\Microsoft.com">Submit</a>
</body>
</html>
```

VBA Code:

```html
Sub demo()
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim Link As Object
Dim ElementCol As Object

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True

ie.navigate "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\demo57.html" 'Change the URL  as your requirement...

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

DoEvents
Loop

Set html = ie.Document
Set ElementCol = html.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each Link In ElementCol

If Link.innerHTML = "Submit" Then
Link.Click

End If
Next Link

Set ie = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Further, You can try to modify the code as per your requirement.